# Data insertion into the hierarchy format from one table to another

Tags: c#, sql, linq, common-table-expression

I have an issue in insertion of records from one table to another the tables schema is same

```
Table 1     
Id  Parent Id   Text
11  Null          A
12  Null          B
13  11            C
14  11            D
15  13            E
```

The record should be inserted in this format, I have to copy the foreign key relation not the identities of it.

```
Table 2     
Id  Parent Id   Text
31  Null         A
32  Null         B
33  31           C
34  31           D
35  33           E
```

Comment: what is the difference between the two tables other than the Id values of the five rows?

Comment: One is the temp table and the other one is the main table, both the tables have the same schema only the records are different.

Both the tables have identity column so the no. of records can be different

Comment: Is there any relationship between the identity column of table1 and identity column of table2?

Comment: nope they are not holding any relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this question.

Steps:
Insert the Text column values into the main table, leaving the ParentId as null and at the same time insert the values into a Dictionary as oldId key and New Inserted Id as value to the corresponding key.

After insertion Update the values on the basis of the mapped Dictionary keyValue Pair

Answer (score 0):

What you want could be achieved easily in the `Database` side.
But since you are looking for a `linq` approach. Here is how it can be achieved.

The Process is divided into two parts:

Hoping that you would have the model for the `Table1` and `Table2` something like(*use the order you think is helpful. For my thinking the `Table1` is the temp table*):

```
Public class myEntity
{
  public int Id{get; set;}
  public int? ParentId{get; set;}
  public string Text{get; set;}
}
```

**1st**: Copying all the `Text` Properties from `Table A` and inserting them into `Table B` with incrementing the `IDs`

```
var Table2 = new List<myEntity>();

Table1.Select(s=>s.Text).OrderBy(o=>o).ToList().ForEach(f=>
{
    //now append the texts to 
    Table2.Add(new tablesTest { Id = (Table2.Count + 1), Text = f });//remove the Id property manupulation or set it to 0 if you are inserting directly in the database and use the context.SaveChanges();(*if entity-framework*) once the insertion is complete.
}}
```

**2nd**: Creating a mapping table using `self-join` to get the parent-child relationship between the entries from `Table1` and then updating the entries in `Table2`

```
var parentChildListFromTb1 = from m in Table1
                      join ch in Table1 on m.Id equals ch.ParentId
                      select new
                      {
                         Id = ch.Id,                             
                         Parent = m.Text,
                         Text = ch.Text
                      };
```

Which will give you an output:

```
----------------------------
|  Id  |  Parent  |  Text  |
----------------------------
|  13  |    A     |    C   |
----------------------------
|  14  |    A     |    D   |
----------------------------
|  15  |    C     |    E   |
----------------------------
```

Now after we have the `parent-child` list now we create the child list by querying `Table2` and updating its ParentId with their respected Ids:

```
parentChildListFromTb1.ForEach(f=>{
            var ChildEntity = Table2.Single(s => s.Text.Equals(f.Text));//fetching the child entity from Table2
            ChildEntity.ParentId = Table2.Single(s => s.Text.Equals(f.Parent)).Id;//updating the parentIds in Table2
});
```

And the `Table2` will look something like :

```
------------------------------
|  Id  |  ParentId  |  Text  |
------------------------------
|   1  |    null    |    A   |
------------------------------
|   2  |    null    |    B   |
------------------------------
|   3  |     1      |    C   |
------------------------------
|   4  |     1      |    D   |
------------------------------
|   5  |     3      |    E   |
------------------------------
```